# DataTable filtros por fecha

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, datatable

Estoy tratando de utilizar filtros por fecha.

He encontrado varios ejemplos, pero en uno de ellos estoy bloqueado porque pone la fecha y coge ejemplo si selecciono `5 de mayo de 2018` comienza a mostrarme los datos desde el 6.

Lo otro es que, si quiero limpiar el filtro, éste no lo hace. me deja los datos filtrados estáticos:

Este es el código:

```js
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date <= minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date >= maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Date_search").val("");
});


var table = $('#tabla').DataTable({
  language: {
    "decimal": "",
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  },
  deferRender: true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "search": {
    "regex": true,
    "caseInsensitive": false,
  },
});

$("#Date_search").daterangepicker({
  "locale": {
    "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "separator": " to ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "a",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "weekLabel": "W",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      "Do",
      "Lu",
      "Ma",
      "Mi",
      "Ju",
      "Vi",
      "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
      "Enero",
      "Febrero",
      "Marzo",
      "Abril",
      "Mayo",
      "Junio",
      "Julio",
      "Agosto",
      "Septiembre",
      "Octubre",
      "Noviembre",
      "Diciembre"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
  },
  "opens": "center",
}, function(start, end, label) {
  maxDateFilter = end;
  minDateFilter = start;
  table.draw();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" /> Fecha a buscar: <input id="Date_search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar por fecha" /><br>

<table id='tabla'>
  <thead>
    <td>Fecha</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-09</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-05-10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```